# CIDetector iOS 64-bit "No suitable image found"

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have trouble with an app that I am developing right now. There's a similar question already out there ([Core Image face detection broken on 64 bit iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018962/core-image-face-detection-broken-on-64-bit-ios)) but it doesn't cover what I'm looking for. I have an cocos2d app using CIDetectorTypeFace which is not working because of the following ERROR,

"FaceCore: Throwing runtime error exception: dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/fcl-fc-3.dat, 2): no suitable image found. Did find: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/fcl-fc-3.dat: mach-o, but wrong architecture",

on my 64-bit iPhone 5s. The problem is that face detection is working with OpenGL and SpriteKit also running on my iPhone 5s with 64-bit architecture. Any idea what is going?

```
- (void)updateTexture:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
{
    imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);


    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

    width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    if(!textureAtlas_.texture) {


       CCTexture2D *texture = [[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithData:baseAddress
                                                  pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888
                                                   pixelsWide:width
                                                   pixelsHigh:height
                                                  contentSize:CGSizeMake(width,height)
                             ] autorelease];

    [self setTexture:texture];
    }


    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture.name);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, baseAddress);

    if(!isProcessingImage) {

        pixelBuffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        currentImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];

        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(findFaces) withObject:nil];
    }
}
```

CIDetector setup

```
NSString *accuracy = CIDetectorAccuracyHigh;
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:accuracy  forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy];
CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:options];
NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:currentImage];
```

And currentImage is the image I'm using for the face detection part.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the code that shows the `CIDetector` stuff? How did you setup the AV capture, what is the pixel format?

Comment: When you have an error message, post **all of the message**.  Best guess, it sounds like you are linking against a library that does not contain an arm64 slice.

Comment: @bbum, yes, that's correct. But why is it working with my sprite kit and opengl example? Will post all of the error message next time and edit this one tomorrow! Tark, can add code tomorrow, but the setup of both avcapture and cidetector is prettt standard. Thanks to both of you for replying!

Comment: @Tark, don't know if it's necessary to provide with the setup for my AVCaptureSession, but the pixel format I'm using for the videoDataOutput is: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA. Also added the code for the CIDetector setup. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I continued my search around the web looking for answers. Did find one stating that the issue would be solved in iOS 7.1. I recently installed iOS 7.1, and now CIDetector is working fine.

Comment: You installed 7.1 ? From where ? I think its not released yet.

Comment: Hey, Omer! I'm registered as an apple developer and I can download beta versions of iOS! I believe it soon will be released for everyone else too.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the Architectures(click the app ->Build Settings) in project to “Standard Architectures (including 64-bit)(armv7, armv7s, arm64).”, and then it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Rachel! Yes, I did that too, but there was a problem with iOS 7.0. Apple said that they would fix this in 7.1 which they did! But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and it is working with Xcode5.1 beta5.